# Unable to access the navigation property of a newly created object

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an asp.net core MVC framework + entity framework. where i got those model classes:-

```
public partial class Submission
{
    public Submission()
    {
        SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }

public partial class SubmissionQuestion
    {
        public SubmissionQuestion()
        {
            SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }

public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
    {
        public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }
        public long SubmissionId { get; set; }
        public bool? Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
        public virtual SubmissionQuestion SubmissionQuestion { get; set; }
    }

public class SubmissionCreate
    {
        public Submission Submission {set; get;}
        public IList<SubmissionQuestion> SubmissionQuestion { set; get; }

        public IList<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { set; get; }

    }
```

and i have the following create view:-

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubmissionQuestion.Count(); i++)
                {

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question" hidden />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].SubmissionQuestionId" hidden />
                        <label class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold">@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label><br />
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" value="true" /><span style="color: #4d9b84;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold"> Yes</span><br />
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" value="false" /><span style="color: #4d9b84;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold"> No</span>


                    </div>

                }
```

and the following create post method:-

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Submission,SubmissionQuestionSubmission")] SubmissionCreate sc )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              var newsubmission  =  _context.Submission.Add(sc.Submission);
                sc.Submission.Created = DateTime.Now;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                foreach (var v in sc.SubmissionQuestionSubmission)
                {

                    v.SubmissionId = sc.Submission.Id;
                    _context.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Add(v);
                }
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but inside my action method if i try the following `sc.Submission.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SubmissionQuestion.Question.StartsWith("Are you")).Answer` i will get null reference exception where the `sc.Submission.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.SubmissionQuestion` will be null, although the relation of these objects are defined inside the database.. any advice?

Comment: If `sc` isn't fully loaded will all of these relationships when entering the method, why do you expect it to be later?

Comment: You could not get the navigation property because `sc` is the object received from your View instead of database.Only if your view contains such property that you could receive what you want.

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault could be null in any case. It doesn't related to this particular case. So, before using any property, it should be checked whether it is null or not.

```
var object = list.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.p1='aa');
if(object != null)
{
    //use object.Answer
}
```